# How to check for file existence

Tags: ruby, file

Is there a Ruby class/method where I could pass "a full path", `home/me/a_file.txt`, to identify whether it is a valid file path?

Comment: My advice is to spend 10 minutes reading all the methods in FileUtils and File classes. It will save you a lot of time in the long run!

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to know "whether it is a valid file path" or "whether it is a path to a file that exists"?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Check out [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) and in particular [`Pathname#exist?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-exist-3F).

[File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) and its [FileTest](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/FileTest.html) module are perhaps simpler/more direct, but I find `Pathname` a nicer interface in general.

Comment: thanks Paul, Pathname is what I needs. Somehow i am not able to find "File" and "FileTest" are accepting "FULL" path argument. Thanks again

Comment: Pathname is very useful but it's not a complete replacement for File and FileTest. It's easy to extend it so that it does have the same tests though, and then its utility as a wrapper really shines.

Answer (score 691):

```
# file? will only return true for files
File.file?(filename)
```

and

```
# Will also return true for directories - watch out!
File.exist?(filename)
```

Comment: just File.file? should be enough, no?
Docs: "Returns true if the named file exists and is a regular file"

Comment: Important to note that the "and" above is not code: `File.exist?(filename) and File.file?(filename)` would always return false since File.exist? "Returns true if the named file is a directory, false otherwise."

Comment: Sorry chris you are wrong true and false => false
`
>> File.file?('/etc/passwd')
=> true
>> File.file?('/etc/')
=> false
>> File.exists?('/etc/')
=> true
>> File.exists?('/etc/passwd')
=> true
>> File.file?('/etc/passwd') and File.exists?('/etc/passwd')`

Comment: exists? is now depreciated.

Comment: @MarkDavies - Where ? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/File.html which is the current version still valid there.

Comment: @user3788685: My comment was In response to "shadowbq" comment.  They used an example of the "exists?" method and "exists?" is depreciated.  However, "exist?" is current.

Comment: @MarkDavies I don't mean to spam, but the word is deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208091/the-difference-between-deprecated-depreciated-and-obsolete

Comment: Yes you're right.