# Obsolete vs. Deprecated HTML

Tags: html

What is the difference between the terms "obsolete" and "deprecated" with regards to HTML? I seem to be seeing a lot of elements being flagged as "obsolete" in HTML5...

Comment: Just wanted to mention I made a bookmarklet for removing obsolete attributes from your markup on the fly and it spits out the 'generated' source so you can see what you need to get rid of in your code. Feel free to use it. http://keithwyland.github.com/attrebuke/

Comment: Related post - [The Difference Between Deprecated, Depreciated and Obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208091/465053)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the HTML 4.01 specification, clause [4.1 Definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/conform.html#h-4.1) defines “deprecated” and “obsolete” as technical terms. Briefly, a deprecated feature is something that you should not use, but browsers should keep supporting it. An obsolete feature is something that is just listed for historical purposes, not defined, and no browser support is required (though in practice it typically still exists). HTML 4.01 declares most of the old presentational elements and attributes as deprecated. Only a few very elements of little importance are declared as obsolete there.

In the W3C HTML5 draft, the terminology is different. It does not use the word “deprecated” at all (except when referring to the use of this word in HTML 4.01). It does not define “obsolete” as a technical term (as applicable to features of HTML), but it uses the word a lot. The word is implicitly defined in the [11 Obsolete features](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) section. The draft tells, with somewhat varying tones and specialties depending on features, authors not to use obsolete features but expects browsers to keep supporting them. It also contains detailed descriptions of their syntax and semantics, partly even more detailed than in older specifications.

In the HTML5 draft, most of the obsolete features are also classified as “non-conforming”, with the statement that they “must not be used by authors”. These features cover most of the features that are deprecated in HTML 4.01, and some more, including features that were not in HTML 4.01 at all.

For example, the `font` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01, obsolete in HTML5. So in principle, HTML 4.01 you should not use, HTML5 says you shall not use it (and HTML5 validators are told to issue error message, not just a warning). In practice, the difference is smaller, mostly just a matter of principle. Browsers are still required to parse the element and add it to the document tree, and they are expected to implement it as before.

Comment: Thanks! That was incredibly helpful!

Comment: Any references to your last sentence "Browsers are still required to support the element."?

Comment: @Pacerier, clause [11.3.4 Other elements, attributes and APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#other-elements,-attributes-and-apis) says: “The font element must implement the HTMLFontElement interface.” This includes the old attributes. Clause [10.3.4 Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0) describes the visual effect. Admittedly, this is just “suggested rendering”, so I’ll modify the wording; it’s formally not a requirement but a strong recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

The dictionary tells the story pretty well:

**[Deprecated](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/deprecate?q=deprecated)**: Express disapproval of.

**[Obsolete](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/obsolete?q=obsolete)**: No longer produced or used; out of date.

It is *recommended* that you don't use [deprecated elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/conform.html#deprecated), because they will likely not be supported in the future, whereas *[obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/conform.html#didx-obsolete)* elements have already been discontinued from use.

Comment: I like [this definition](http://computer.yourdictionary.com/deprecate) for deprecate better. *To make invalid or obsolete by removing or flagging the item. When commands or statements in a language are planned for deletion in future releases of the compiler or rendering engine, they are said to be deprecated. Programmers should begin to remove them from the source code in subsequent revisions of their programs.*

Comment: This is not really specific to the question about HTML

Answer (score 0):

Obsolete generally means that it has been replaced with something else.

Deprecated means that future developments may not support it.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you reference a blog post that subsequently links to the W3 specification regarding obsolete elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete

So as the blog you linked to eludes, obsolete elements should never be used, there are alternatives available. For deprecated elements, browsers will generally still support and render them for backwards-compatibility, but your page will not pass conformance validation.