# How to choose DeprecatedAttribute and ObsoleteAttribute in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes

I found the question [Obsolete vs. Deprecated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784301/obsolete-vs-deprecated-html), but not one about C#. How can I choose `DeprecatedAttribute` and `ObsoleteAttribute` in C#?

I just found there is a solution in documented on MSDN [ObsoleteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[Obsolete("This class is obsolete; Use the new one instead")]
class OBClass
{
    public void OBMethod() { }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much it I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759352/how-do-i-mark-a-method-as-obsolete-deprecated

Comment: If you mean this `DeprecatedAttribute` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.deprecatedattribute.aspx - then it can't be considered as alternative for `ObsoleteAttrubute`. In fact, this is different frameworks.

Comment: @Dennis yes,you are right. I'm not sure about DeprecatedAttribute  . I just found the question from a tech quiz