# Difference between obsolete and waste code

Tags: obsolete

What is the difference between terms: "obsolete code" and "waste code"?
If there is the difference, what approaches are eligible for its reduction?

Comment: I think programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question.

Comment: Related post - [The Difference Between Deprecated, Depreciated and Obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208091/465053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Obsolete code:**

Code that may have been useful in the past, but is no longer used, e.g. code to use a deprecated protocol.

**Waste code:**

Never heard of the term, but I'd imagine - code that may or may not be executed that can be removed without changing workings of the application. I'd imagine this would include obsolete code.

Either of the above can range from single statements to entire libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say that obsolete code are methods that are there, but aren't used any more. Like for example deprecated methods/functions. Waste code would I define as code that has as only function to slow the application down.