# whats the harm in using deprecated html tags intentionally?

Tags: html

After watching Mathias Bynens insanely cool css seminar on the quirky facts about css and html. I started thinking a lot about semantics, why can't we use old depreciated html tags in new ways? for example:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <menu title=deprecated>
             <li>Foo
             <li>Bar
             <li>Thunder
             <li>Flash
        </menu>
    </nav>    
</header>
```

so the question is, What is wrong with recycling html tags, could this set trends or bad practices?

Comment: This markup hurts...physically. It's not good practice because conventions and standards exist for a reason.

Comment: Tip: It's _deprecated_, not _depreciated_. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208091/the-difference-between-deprecated-depreciated-and-obsolete

Comment: Excuse: Dyslexia sorry

Comment: @gibsonman507 He's asking what that reason is.

Comment: Interesting reaction, but this is all valid html5 apart from <menu> which was once in the html5 spec, but was dropped, I'm guessing because the markup hurt many eyes.

If we focus on menus, <ul> <li> is best practice but it has to be initially adapted to be fit for purpose, list-style:none; yet its still best practice. This article about custom html tags might give you the chills [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

Comment: @AdamMilesCrockett - menu was dropped from the HTML5 spec because there weren't going to be implementations ready in time to avoid it stopping HTML5 transitioning to recommendation status. The [menu](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element) element is still very much part of the HTML5.1 spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated has a specific meaning and purpose. Deprecation typically occurs because a better way to do something has been determined, and it is time to phase out the old way. These sorts of decisions are generally not made in a capricious way. There is usually very good purpose for making these sorts of changes.

Using deprecated functionality intentionally is a bad practice because, in the case of HTML,  at any given time a browser can choose to stop supporting the deprecated functionality. That leaves your code broken and in need of maintenance.

Comment: Thanks that's a perfectly clear and insightful answer. It makes me think about the user-agent and how styles are preset according to spec. if I created this: <foo>custom</foo> chrome for example, would render this, it would probably have no style and would need to be defined every time which would be irritating and bad practice, should I be looking at this in the same way as depreciated tags? 

Rest assured my question is hypothetical.

Comment: You are correct, you really don't want to rely on a specific feature of a specific browser. Generally, you want to build sites through progressive enhancement, where the most basic features work in all browsers and then enhancements are layered on top for specific browsers through feature detection. You can find a lot of good information on feature detection and progressive enhancement. Both will help you build much better sites with a lot less frustration.

Comment: @AdamMilesCrockett Another relevant point is that something that isn't currently part of any standard may still be added to a future specification - meaning that, unless your definition by some fluke perfectly matches with the future standard, your site suddenly stops working at some future data as browsers are updated to support the new element. It's worth noting that elements deprecated under XHTML have also been resurrected under HTML5 and even the fact something has been removed from the spec doesn't make it fair game for custom use.