# Check if image file exists using middleman

Tags: ruby, image, file, middleman

I have a website running on middleman. I'm trying to check if an image file exists. I followed the suggestion in "[How to check for file existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590098/ruby-function-to-check-file-existence)", using `File.file?`, but it's not working. Here's the line of code:

```
<% if File.exists?("/source/images/doctor-#{doctor.slug}.jpg") %>
```

I tried a few different file paths:

- /source/images/file
- /images/file
- ../images/file

but none worked. In the browser, I can view the image file at "0.0.0.0:4567/images/file".

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"../source/images/doctor-#{doctor.slug}.jpg"`

Comment: You're confusing the path to the file as the server reports it to the browser, vs. how the interpreter and scripts see it when looking at the disk. The two are very different.

Comment: I tried "../source/images/doctor-#{doctor.slug}.jpg" and it didn't work either. Ug.

Comment: Try `"./source/images/doctor-#{doctor.slug}.jpg"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to query those files via the [Middleman Sitemap](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/sitemap/)?

You gain access to it within templates via the `sitemap` object. One way of achieving your actual case could be:

```
<% if sitemap.find_resource_by_path("images/doctor-#{doctor.slug}.jpg") %>
    <%# do what you want %>
<% end %>
```