# How to check whether a File exists

Tags: ruby, path, pathname

I have an Array of Strings and I want to select only these Strings which are paths to files:

My path is `"~/dlds/some_file.ics"` where `~/dlds` is a symlink to `~/archive/downloads` on my system. The file has following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

My code (I tried several variants):

```
ARGV.select do |string|
    File.file? string # returns false
    Pathname.new(string).file? # returns false
    Pathname.new(string).expand_path.file? # returns false
end
```

I don't know what else to try.

I'm running Ruby 2.2.0 or 2.2.2.

Comment: Show your `ARGV` please

Comment: I think the reason is in the `~/` directory. To check it try to pass the full path ie `/home/user/dlds/some_file.ics`

Comment: ARGV: `["--debug", "~/dlds/some_file"]`. Using a full path doesn't work as well..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
File.exist? File.expand_path "~/dlds/some_file.ics"
```

Comment: note this returns true if the path is also a directory. details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590098/ruby-function-to-check-file-existence

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. If you want to check if the file exists, you should just do as you did:

```
Pathname.new(file_name).file?
```

If you are using the `~` you will first have to expand the path, so write:

```
Pathname.new(file_name).expand_path.file?
```

If you want to check if the given `file_name` is a symlink, you can just do

```
Pathname.new(file_name).expand_path.symlink?
```

If you want to find the file the symlink points to, you have to follow the link:

```
File.readlink(Pathname.new(file_name).expand_path)
```

which will return the filename of the linked file, so if you really wanted you could do something like:

```
Pathname.new(File.readlink(Pathname.new(file_name).expand_path)).file?
```

to make sure the symlink is pointing to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

I think [File.readlink](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-readlink) is what you are looking for

> Returns the name of the file referenced by the given link. Not
>   available on all platforms.

```
File.readlink("path/to/symlink")
```

Comment: Results in `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_readlink - ~/dlds/some_file`

Comment: This should work. From the error you show you supplied the incorrect filename.

Comment: The filename was auto-completed when I tried in irb, so no, I know that the file exists and the path is correct.