# How to check if a file exists

Tags: ruby

So my problem is basically is that I can't figure out a condition to give an error message if can't find the file given as argument.

```
if ARGV.empty?
    puts "Give me a file!"
elseif [condition]
    puts "Can't find the file"
else
    file = File.open(ARGV[0])
```

What I exactly need is the condition for the elseif.

Comment: Ruby's `File.open` will throw an exception if it cannot find the file.  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for file existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590098/how-to-check-for-file-existence)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`File.exist?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F), e.g.

```
2.3.0 :003 > File.exist? 'foo'
 => false
```